# fortran extended types over different modules

Tags: fortran, fortran2003

With extended types in Fortran should a private component by visible to a type extension in a different module.

With both gcc4.7 and ifort the following code results in a error since bName is in both the initial type and the extension. But since it's private, it isn't accesible in the extension in a different module, i.e., if you comment out bName in the bar_type you will get an error that it's private.

```
module foo
  type :: foo_type
    character(256),private :: bName = "foo"
  contains
    procedure :: pName => pName
  end type
contains
  subroutine pName(this)
    class(foo_type), intent(in) :: this
    print*,trim(this%bName)
  end subroutine
end module

module bar
  use foo, only : foo_type
  type,extends(foo_type) :: bar_type
    character(256),private :: bName = "bar"
  contains
    procedure :: pName => pName
  end type
contains

  subroutine pName(this)
    class(bar_type), intent(in) :: this
    print*,this%bName
  end subroutine
end module


program test
  use foo, only : foo_type
  use bar, only : bar_type
  type(foo_type) :: foo_inst
  type(bar_type) :: bar_inst

  call foo_inst%pName()
  call bar_inst%pName()
end program
```

If bar_type was contained in the same module as foo_type, then bName would be accessible from bar_type, i.e., the following code will compile

```
module foo
  type :: foo_type
    character(256),private :: bName = "foo"
  contains
    procedure :: pName => pName
  end type

  type, extends(foo_type) :: baz_type
  contains
    procedure :: pName => pName_baz
  end type
contains
  subroutine pName_baz(this)
    class(baz_type), intent(in) :: this
    print*,trim(this%bName)
  end subroutine

  subroutine pName(this)
    class(foo_type), intent(in) :: this
    print*,trim(this%bName)
  end subroutine
end module

program test
  use foo, only : foo_type,baz_type
  type(foo_type) :: foo_inst
  type(baz_type) :: baz_inst

  call foo_inst%pName()
  call baz_inst%pName()
end program
```

Been having a hard time parsing the standards to know what should happen in the first example.

Comment: Hi Jeremy. I am having the exact same issue. Have you figure out how to separate base and derive types in different modules as well as access a private base member in derived member? Thx.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the first example is not standard-conforming.

Even though the private attribute makes the component `bName` inaccessible outside module `foo`, it is still inherited by `bar_type` (perhaps rather pointless, because nothing can be done with it, but that's not the issue) -- see Note 4.51 in f2003:

> Inaccessible components and bindings of the parent type are also inherited, but they remain inaccessible
>   in the extended type. Inaccessible entities occur if the type being extended is accessed via
>   use association and has a private entity.

So `bar_type` has an inherited component with the name `bName`, which makes it an error to add another component by that name (see paragraph 16.2 for scope and name rules).